# How to identify improperly encoded string python?

Tags: python, encoding

I have following string

```
my_str = 'ґрµ р рѕр рґр сџ сѓрµр сњсѓрєрѕс рґрµсџс сњрѕрѕсѓс рїрѕ с рѕс рїсђрѕрёр сџ рјсѓс рґр сџ рер рµрѕрёсџ рєрѕсђрјрѕрі'
```

This string has been encoded improperly which is obvious. But is there way to automatically detect this ?

It's not a `mojibake`. I tried following

```
from ftfy.badness import badness
badness(my_str)
```

which returns 0 which means that is not mojibake. Also i tried

```
ftfy.fix_text(my_str)
```

which returns the original string `my_str`.

If i try to encode it and than encode

```
my_str.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
```

the result is:

```
Ò\x91Ñ\x80Âµ Ñ\x80 Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80 Ñ\x80Ò\x91Ñ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x80ÂµÑ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9aÑ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x80Ñ\x94Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ò\x91Ñ\x80ÂµÑ\x81Ñ\x9fÑ\x81 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9aÑ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ñ\x97Ñ\x80Ñ\x95 Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ñ\x97Ñ\x81Ñ\x92Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x91Ñ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x80Ñ\x98Ñ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ò\x91Ñ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x80ÐµÑ\x80 Ñ\x80ÂµÑ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x91Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x80Ñ\x94Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81Ñ\x92Ñ\x80Ñ\x98Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x96
```

or

```
my_str.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
```

which returns

```
Ò\x91Ñ\x80Âµ Ñ\x80 Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80 Ñ\x80Ò\x91Ñ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x80ÂµÑ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9aÑ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x80Ñ\x94Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ò\x91Ñ\x80ÂµÑ\x81Ñ\x9fÑ\x81 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9aÑ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ñ\x97Ñ\x80Ñ\x95 Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ñ\x97Ñ\x81Ñ\x92Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x91Ñ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x80Ñ\x98Ñ\x81Ñ\x93Ñ\x81 Ñ\x80Ò\x91Ñ\x80 Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x80ÐµÑ\x80 Ñ\x80ÂµÑ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x91Ñ\x81Ñ\x9f Ñ\x80Ñ\x94Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x81Ñ\x92Ñ\x80Ñ\x98Ñ\x80Ñ\x95Ñ\x80Ñ\x96
```

or

```
my_str.encode('utf-8').decode('Windows-1254')
```

i got

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 25: character maps to <undefined>
```

My problem is that i don't know the original encoding, in this case this is some russian string probably Windows-1254 that has been encoded to UTF-8. I am looking for something like

```
def bad_encoding(str_) -> bool:
     return True if string has been encoded bad else False
```

Comment: If you have a string like so in a `str`, it would be represented as unicode and conversion back to what it might have been will have to be done on a trial and error basis, and it may not succeed because you have a fully formed `str` and whatever produced this may have dropped bytes that could not be correctly encoded to produce that output, and those dropped bytes will not be recoverable.

Comment: Moreover, [this section](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/detect.html) of the documentation to `ftfy` discusses the problems of what you may be trying to solve.

Comment: Yea, this is returns sloppy-windows-1252 encoding for both bad and good string and i still don't know how to recognize it

Comment: Without knowing exactly what were the original bytes were that produced `my_str` as unicode, it is **impossible** to determine what it may have originally be.  You may have a better chance of getting help if you explain how this Cyrillic looking string is malformed and what the output should have been.

Comment: Ok, let's start with good looking Cyrillic string - 'Привет, как дела' and bad one - 'рўрѕрісђрµрјрµрѕрѕс рґрёр '

Comment: What was `рўрѕрісђрµрјрµрѕрѕс рґрёр` supposed to decode to?

Comment: More to the point - if you can figure out the exact encoding/decoding step to produce that unwanted output, you may be able to apply the reverse step to get back the original intended human readable text, **assuming no bytes were dropped to produce the unwanted gibberish**

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to identify the exact encoding of string. You can check for most common ones and build the Boolean function using try/exception.

```
def bad_encoding(text):
try:
    text = text.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')
    return False
except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
    try:
        text = text.encode('cp1252').decode(
            'latin-1').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
        return False
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still got False for i good string 'Привет, как дела'